# how launch background threads (multi-threads) without blocking main thread in Swift?

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift

I am trying to execute a thread in "captureOutput" function. This function is called every 1/X s (X depending of fps of the camera devices). For example, if camera settings is 30fps, every 0'03s will be called.

Now, I want to create a thread and execute it in a different context, when ends send the result to the main thread and continuous accepting new frames.

To do this I try to use GDC, like this:

```
 private var processImageQueue:dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("process_image", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)


    dispatch_async(processImageQueue, {

        println("new despatch");



        let resultFrame:[Frames] = processImages(sampleBuffer,self.countFrames)

          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.insertFrames(resultFrame)
           })

   })
```

But this execution block the Frames getter. Why? What is the best option to create a Multi-threading process? NSOperation? I also try it, but the same thing, I don't get the same frame ratio capture.

thanks